# GEE: apply ee.Reducer.mean to a list

Tags: classification, google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, accuracy, average

After classification of an image in GEE, I got 2 lists of user's and producer's accuracies (1*7 and 7*1 dimensions). How can I calculate an average value for each of them now?

```js
print('Validation consumersAccuracy: ', testAccuracy.consumersAccuracy());
print('Validation producersAccuracy: ', testAccuracy.producersAccuracy());
```

Applying the list reducer does not work.

```js
var meanConsumer=ee.List(testAccuracy.consumersAccuracy()).reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
```

Here is the whole code (it's not actually mine, I am new at GEE)
https://code.earthengine.google.com/b9ebf87363121a6e51a980dfea187166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a bit tricky, since GEE prints the result of `.consumersAccuracy` as the type `List` but the function actually returns an `Array` (see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeconfusionmatrixconsumersaccuracy)).

The array is 1-dimensional and as such the console interprets/displays it as a list. To get the mean you have to use an array instead of a list reducer. Note that the array reducers requires the axis to reduce over - in the case of a 1D array that would be [0,1].

```js
print('Mean consumersAccuracy:', testAccuracy.consumersAccuracy().reduce(ee.Reducer.mean(), [0,1]))
```

Comment: It works now! Thanks a lot, Kersten, for your help!